# Send From Mobile Template to Default Template using cookies

Tags: php, cookies, mobile

I am trying to use php to link from my mobile site to my default site. I am able to set the cookie on the theme page but when I get redirect back to the default page it just redirects me to the mobile page. I can see the cookie gets created but for some reason it wont read the cookie. Any ideas? On a side note is it right to be using a php cookie to do this?

The Code:

Default Templates Index page

```
<?php
    if(isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])){
      exit;
    }
    else{
      // use detectmobilebrowser code to redirect it to m.defaultthemeurl.com
    }
?>
```

Mobile Theme:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['default'])) {
    setcookie('cookie', '1', time()+165*10, '/', 'defaultthemeurl.com');
    header('Location: http://defaultthemeurl.com');
    exit;
}
?>
<a href="?default">logout</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because

```
<a href="?default">logout</a>
```

doesn't actually add a value to $_GET['default'] so the isset() failed.

try

```
<a href="?default=foo">logout</a>
```

instead